# Как проверить, что при компиляции действительно используются предкомпилированные заголовки?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

Согласно документации https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html имеется возможность иметь несколько вариантов одного предкомпилированного заголовка. Для этого надо создать каталог с именем типа all.h.gch и указать на него компилятору, после чего он автоматически выберет подходящий.

Я, с помощью отдельных makefile, создаю в каталоге all.h.gch несколько заголовков типа all1.h.gch, all2.h.gch, и т.д.

После этого, в makefile проекта, которы, я указываю путь до этого каталога: -I/path/to/all.h.gch.

Согласно документации, это должно привести к использованию предкомпилированного заголовка, но, судя по тому, что время компиляции изменяется в пределах статистической погрешности, этого не происходит.

Каким способом можно гарантированно проверить, компилируется ли заголовок каждый раз заново, либо же используется предкомпилированный, не измеряя время компиляции?

Comment: ¿А в чем смысл использовать прекомпилированный заголовок, если он не будет сокращать время сборки? *" помощью отдельных makefile, создаю..."* - этот вопрос был бы куда толковее, если бы был приведен [mcve], на котором использование прекомпилированного заголовка не давало бы заметного результата на время сборки.

Comment: Проверяйте время последнего чтения заголовочного файла. Если оно не изменилось во время последней компиляции, значит файл не читали, значит его содержимое где-то кешировалось.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Мне представляется, что такое не прокатит. Если аргументы компилятора указаны верно, то файлы будут читаться, но при этом их содержимое компилятор может проигнорировать, если определит, что оно не совместимо с настройками текущей сборки.

Comment: @user7860670, если файлы читаются, время последнего чтения обновляется. Я полагаю что при использовании  pch/gch, сами заголовочные файлы не читаются, проверяется только их дата.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy *"Я полагаю что при использовании pch/gch, сами заголовочные файлы не читаются"*  - файлы должны читаться, без вариантов. ¿Иначе как компилятор поймет, какие параметры сборки использовались при записи этих файлов?

Comment: @user7860670, файлы (заголовочные файлы `*.h`, `*.hpp`) не читаются, если их дата совпадает с той что сохранена в `*.pch`/`*.gch`. Я предлагал проверять время последнего чтения `*.h` файла.